# Method as an argument with self parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Disregard the naming conventions as to what class is part of which it is just a test run.

I need some help with the OOP inheritance i have created a class of Students, Teachers, and the principal. My goal is for the principal to be able to add employees. The problem is i just want to use a for loop to get the names and then pass that method as an attribute for the principal object. i was able to do it with the class Input without the self parameter. can someone tell me
what is going on here and how can i fix this with self. i removed input from names so that my question wont get shut down

```
class Input:
     def count():
        cnt = []
        for i in range(4):
            name = ('Enter name here: ')
            cnt.append(name)
        return cnt


class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname

class StudentCouncil(Student):
    def __init__(self, name, lastname, tenure):
        super().__init__(name,lastname)
        self.tenure = tenure


class Principal(StudentCouncil):
    def __init__(self, name, lastname, tenure,employees=None):
        super().__init__(name,lastname,tenure)
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def display(self):
        for names in self.employees:
            print(names,end=' ')




count = Input.count()
tij = Principal('Mike','Thoma','3',count)
tij.display()
```

Comment: It seems odd to classify a teacher as a type of student

Comment: Conceptual question: why is a `Teacher` a *type of* `Student`? That inheritance doesn't make sense. Same with a `Principal`

Comment: furthermore, is a Principal a type of Student? because that seems odd. Also, `Input` shouldn't need to be a class, just a bare method

Comment: "can someone tell me what is going on here and how can i fix this with self"? What do you want to happen, and what goes wrong when running your current code?

Comment: Yea disregard the titles, i was just practicing. The input is what am interested in any ideas?? a teacher can also be a Student at the same institution by the way

Comment: @C.Nivs there will be a runtime error if that function in `Input` is used as a method, but the definition is "valid".

Comment: Your use of inheritance says *all* teachers are students.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah took a second look and saw `Input` wasn't being instantiated

Comment: @Tjs01 it still doesn't make sense. That an individual teacher can be a student is irrelevant, you have stated that *A teacher is a type of Student*, which is simply a confused design. Also, C.Nivs comment about your `Input` class is important, if you are using a class like: `SomeClass.some_function()` where you class has no internal state, then it shouldn't be a class. Your question seems to be about this, but I don't really understand exactly what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A student council *consists* of students, it is not a *kind* of student.

Comment: The work of who inherits from what might seem like semantics, but it's not. It influences the design of how those classes share attributes, behaviors, etc. What it sounds like you're looking for is `Employer` and `Employee` classes, and an `Employee` is not a type of `Employer`. The `Employer` oversees multiple employees

Comment: @scnerd nothing is wrong i just want to know whether its OK to leave the method as  it is or does it need self.

Comment: IMHO, a better way of achieve what you want would be to collect employees first and then pass them to the Principal instantiation

Comment: @Tjs01 no, your `Input` class is not OK. It makes no sense and would be confusing. You are getting it to work by using the class incorrectly. Don't do that. You can add `self` then instantiate an `Input` object, but it probably makes sense to simply not use an `Input` class at all, and just use a normal function

Comment: Also, **don't put a big, all-caps warning telling us to disregard something**. It is your job to create a [mcve]. If you want it to be disregarded, then don't put it. You could have simply provided your `Input` class definition in that case, however, I would urge you to take peoples advice into account instead of continuing on with your confusion.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i fixed it. I forgot some people see that as yelling. Thanks

Comment: @Tryph That makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `count` is all you want from `Input`, just make it a function:

```
def input_names():
    cnt = []
    for i in range(4):
        name = ('Enter name here: ')
        cnt.append(name)
    return cnt
```

If you want a configurable Input type of some sort, then you want to run `count` on an instance of that, you need `self`:

```
class Input:
     def count(self):
        cnt = []
        for i in range(self.num_names):  # if we need some configuration
            name = ('Enter name here: ')
            cnt.append(name)
        return cnt
```

Else, the kosher way to do this is to use the `staticmethod` decorator:

```
class Input:
     @staticmethod
     def count():
        cnt = []
        for i in range(4):
            name = ('Enter name here: ')
            cnt.append(name)
        return cnt
```

Your current code will work as you use it currently, `Input.count()`, but if you instantiated an input, `Input().count()` would throw an exception. The `staticmethod` decorator ensures that this method is safe to call on either the class directly or on an instance of that class.

Comment: Although, I would say, that a class with no internal state and a single method that is a staticmethod should not be a class

Answer (score 3):

If the method takes a `self` parameter, you need to create an instance of the class. So it would be:

```
class Input:
     def count(self):
        cnt = []
        for i in range(4):
            name = input('Enter name here: ')
            cnt.append(name)
        return cnt
```

and then you would do:

```
myinput = Input()
count = myinput.count()
```

Your `count()` method doesn't use any attributes of `self`, so it doesn't currently need to be written this way. But you might want to redefine it like this:

```
class Input:
    def __init__(self, howmany):
        self.howmany = howman

    def count(self):
        return [input('Enter name here: ') for _ in range(self.howmany)]

myinput = Input(4)
count = myinput.count()
```

Comment: Thanks i will look that up